#  How to set page layout for print Option programmatically for mac App

Tags: cocoa, macos, printing

I need to print the content of my view using my mac app. I get the standard panel for print option. But while previewing my page setup is not proper.

I am using the following code for action on print button

```
- (void)print:(id)sender {


        [[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:staticText] runOperation];
        float horizontalMargin, verticalMargin;

        NSSize bounds = [printInfo imageablePageBounds].size;
        NSSize size = [printInfo paperSize];

        horizontalMargin = 0;
        verticalMargin = 0;
        [self setPrintInfo:[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo]];

        [printInfo setLeftMargin:horizontalMargin];
        [printInfo setRightMargin:horizontalMargin];
        [printInfo setTopMargin:verticalMargin];
        [printInfo setBottomMargin:verticalMargin];


    }
```

[image: have a look at the image attached]

Comment: Please have a look at the image

Comment: So? Maybe you should explain a bit better what you want to achieve if you want an answer...

Comment: I am not clear why the text appears always in the center of the scren, although I have reduced top margin

Comment: I want to show text from top of the page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After much research I got everything working fine.I am using below code & would like to share may be it might help someone in future

```
    [self setPrintInfo:[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo]];
    [printInfo setVerticalPagination:NSAutoPagination];
    float horizontalMargin, verticalMargin;

    horizontalMargin = 0;
    verticalMargin = -100;

    [printInfo setLeftMargin:horizontalMargin];
    [printInfo setRightMargin:horizontalMargin];
    [printInfo setHorizontallyCentered:YES];
    [printInfo setTopMargin:-600];

    [printInfo setBottomMargin:verticalMargin];
    [[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:sampleText] runOperation];
```

Comment: Thanks for going to the trouble of posting this.  A year later I stumbled on the same problem and quickly got it fixed thanks to your diligence.

Comment: Thanks for the post. This reduced the big pain of mine. The only issue for now is with the left margin.
I know its an old post. But would you please help with the issue. The left margin is not getting changed though I am coding it with a different values. It seems Its static.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this myself.

My solution was to do this in Swift:

```
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()
let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView, printInfo: printInfo)
printOperation.printInfo.orientation = NSPaperOrientation(rawValue: 1)! // switch to landscape
printOperation.printInfo.leftMargin = 10
printOperation.printInfo.rightMargin = 10
printOperation.printInfo.topMargin = 10
printOperation.printInfo.bottomMargin = 10
printOperation.runOperation()
```

NSPaperOrientation takes an integer value (0 = portrait, 1 = landscape)

Though can probably tidy things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

C# Version of John Griffiths Answer just in case someone is on Xamarin.Mac

```
  var printInfo = NSPrintInfo.SharedPrintInfo;
  var printOperation = NSPrintOperation.FromView(webContainer.MainFrame.FrameView.DocumentView, printInfo);

  printOperation.PrintInfo.Orientation = NSPrintingOrientation.Portrait;
  printOperation.PrintInfo.LeftMargin = 20;
  printOperation.PrintInfo.RightMargin = 20;
  printOperation.PrintInfo.TopMargin = 50;
                printOperation.PrintInfo.BottomMargin = 50;
                printOperation.RunOperation();
```